# Fast way to generat a list of QVector3D's in python

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside6

I would like to use the `Q3DSurface()` class to plot my data.
In the example, they use a loop to generate the data and convert it to a list of `QVector3D()` objects.

In my case, I have the data as a `numpy.ndarray()`. If I follow the example, I have to iterate through the entire array and convert every element to a `QVector3D()` and save it in a list.

Is there a more efficient way to generate a list of `QVector3D()` elements from a numpy array that I can pass to the `QSurfaceDataProxy()` object?

In my use case, I want to have a live view in a GUI. The updated takes with the code below roughly 0.3s (data.shape=(400,400)). This is way too much for my application.

I tried it with numba, but it does not recognize the `QVector3D()` class.

The code where I parse the array is:

```py
#@jit(nopython=True)    
def update_data(data:np.ndarray):
    vector_list= [[0]*data.shape[1] for i in range(data.shape[0])]
    for y_index in range(data.shape[0]):
        for x_index in range(data.shape[1]):
            vector_list[y_index][x_index] = QVector3D(x_index, data[y_index,x_index], y_index)
    return vector_list
```

Comment: Do you benchmark with multiple iterations? Did you try switching x and y indexing? You can keep the generated matrix and only adjust elements of it on the next computation.

Comment: Yes, I tried it over multiple iterations. I tested it with the generation of the `vector_list` outside the function. This gives a speed-up of roughly 0.08s.
For a real-time view, the time has to be significantly shorter. Optimally an order of 100. So the goal time is a few ms and not a few 100 ms.
I have not tested the speed if I change x and y, but I think as long they are the same size it does not matter.

Comment: Is constructor of QVector3D too heavy? Did you try lru_cache of functools for that? What is possible range of x_index and y_index and data[y,x]? Can they fit memory? If data[y,x] is 8-bit or 16-bit then you can simply have a dictionary of precomputed QVector3D elements.

Comment: The lru_cache of functools helped. However, I had to use this wrapper for numpy arrays [link](https://gist.github.com/Susensio/61f4fee01150caaac1e10fc5f005eb75). This reduced the execution time to 0.07s after the first run. This is already much faster, but it would be nice if I can reduce the time by another factor of 10. The data fits in the memory and could be of type double. The range of the index is normally under 400.

Comment: Is GUI drawing it in "immediate mode" or "retained mode"? Drawing in immediate mode is like sending each vector to GPU one after another, meaning O(N) operations and could be slow in Python. How does vector_list returned work? Does GUI send it at once or one element at a time?

Comment: I send the data all at once to the QT `QSurfaceDataProxy()` object. `self.surface_data.resetArray(vector_list)`. `surface_data` is a `QSurfaceDataProxy()` object, which is passed to a `QSurface3DSeries()` object on initialization and the `QSurface3DSeries()` is added to a `Q3DSurface()`. I used [this](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/examples/example_datavisualization__surface.html) example as a starting point

Answer (score 1):

Here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-data-handling.html, it says

> **Dealing with Real-time Data**
>
> When you have a data set that updates rapidly, it is important to
> handle data properly to ensure good performance. Since memory
> allocation is a costly operation, always use QList::reserve() and
> QVector::resize() where possible to avoid unnecessary reallocations
> when constructing the array to give to the proxy. If you need to
> change the entire data set for each frame, it is in most cases best to
> reuse the existing array - especially if the array dimensions do not
> change. **If you need to add, insert, remove, or change several rows or**
> **items for each frame, it is always more efficient to do it with one**
> **method call instead of multiple calls** affecting a single row or item
> each. For example, adding ten rows with a single
> QBarDataProxy::addRows() call is much more efficient than ten separate
> QBarDataProxy::addRow() calls.
>
> Bars renderer is optimized to access only data that is within the data
> window and thus should not suffer noticeable slowdown even if more
> data is continually added to the proxy.
>
> Due to the unsorted nature of the scatter data, any change in the data
> window ranges requires all data points to be checked for visibility,
> which can cause increasing slowdown if data is continually added to
> the proxy. For the best performance with the scatter graphs, only keep
> the data you need in the proxy.
>
> Surface data, while on item level similar to scatter data, is already
> assigned into rows and columns, so the surface renderer can optimize
> drawing by making the assumption that the data in the rows and columns
> is sorted along their respective axes. It is not quite as efficient as
> in the bars case, but nearly so.

Are you using multiple rows at once or one by one?

Comment: I add them all at once. My `vector_list` is a list of rows. The problem I have is how can I convert my numpy array to something I can pass to a `QSurfaceDataProxy()` object without the costly for loop and `QVector3D()` object generation for every single point. I have a Nx3 numpy array with all my values.